# How do I make sure httpx calls are run in parallel?

Tags: python-asyncio, httpx

I was recommended [httpx](https://www.python-httpx.org/async/#making-async-requests) as a way to perform api requests in parallel, with a nice api like [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

my code

```py
import asyncio
import time

import httpx

async def main():
    t0 = time.time()

    usernames = [
    "author",
    "abtinf",
    "TheCoelacanth",
    "tomcam",
    "chauhankiran",
    "ulizzle",
    "ulizzle",
    "ulizzle",
    "cratermoon",
    "Aeolun",
    "ulizzle",
    "firexcy",
    "kazinator",
    "blacksoil",
    "lucakiebel",
    "ozim",
    "tomcam",
    "jstummbillig",
    "tomcam",
    "johnchristopher",
    "Tade0",
    "lallysingh",
    "paulddraper",
    "WilTimSon",
    "gumby",
    "kristopolous",
    "zemo",
    "aschearer",
    "why-el",
    "Osiris",
    "mdaniel",
    "ianbutler",
    "vinaypai",
    "samtho",
    "chazeon",
    "taeric",
    "yellowapple",
    "Kye",
    ]

    bios = []

    headers = {"User-Agent": "curl/7.72.0"}
    async with httpx.AsyncClient(headers=headers) as client:
        for username in usernames:
            url = f"https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/users/{username}"
            response = await client.get(url)
            data = response.json()
            bios.append(data['about'])
            print('.')

    t1 = time.time()
    total = t1-t0
    print(bios)
    print(f"Total time: {total} seconds") # 11 seconds async

asyncio.run(main())
```

How do I make sure that this example runs with the requests in parallel?

Comment: You can't make sure that the requests are running in parallel, because there is no possibility that they are.  Your script has one Task (`main()`) and doesn't create any extra threads or Processes.  The one and only Task will await each transaction (`await client.get(url)`) before proceeding to the next transaction.  No parallel processing, multithreading or multitasking can happen.  This Task can potentially multitask with another Task, which will proceed while main() is awaiting.

Comment: Look like a simple fix, just create task per request(Which might ban you for ddos-ing on some servers) or go for producer-consumer pattern and create fixed numbers of consumer tasks with a queue. Will answer in bit more detail after few hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, Python's `asyncio` does not provide *true* parallelism (as has been discussed repeatedly on this platform). The event loop runs in a single thread.

The concurrency just allows context switches between multiple coroutines, while they are awaiting some I/O operation to finish, like for example an HTTP request. But the requesting function must be implemented in a particular, non-blocking way for this to work. The `httpx` package apparently provides such functions.

As has been pointed out in the comments, you are not getting *any* concurrency in your code because you are `await`ing  each request made by the client **sequentially** in a `for`-loop. In other words, there is no chance for a new request to be launched, until the previous one returns completely.

A common pattern to concurrently execute the same coroutine with different arguments is to use [`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather). I would suggest to factor out the entire `GET` request as well as the retrieval of the `about` section of the returned data into its own coroutine function and execute whatever number of those you deem appropriate concurrently:

```py
import asyncio
import time

import httpx


BASE_URL = "https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/users"


async def get_bio(username: str, client: httpx.AsyncClient) -> str:
    response = await client.get(f"{BASE_URL}/{username}")
    print(".")
    data = response.json()
    return data["about"]


async def main() -> None:
    t0 = time.time()
    usernames = [
        "author",
        "abtinf",
        "TheCoelacanth",
        # ...
    ]
    headers = {"User-Agent": "curl/7.72.0"}
    async with httpx.AsyncClient(headers=headers) as client:
        bios = await asyncio.gather(*(get_bio(user, client) for user in usernames))
    print(dict(zip(usernames, bios)))
    print(f"Total time: {time.time() - t0:.3} seconds")


asyncio.run(main())
```

Sample output:

```
.
.
.
{'author': '', 'abtinf': 'You can reach me at abtinf@gmail.com or @abtinf.', 'TheCoelacanth': 'thecoelacanth@gmail.com'}
Total time: 0.364 seconds
```

Since this approach allows a great number of HTTP requests to be made in a very short amount of time (because you are not awaiting previous responses before launching more requests), there is always the danger of being subjected to rate limiting or being blocked outright by the API. I don't know anything about this API in particular though. So I don't know if your list of user names is already "too long".

---

If you are interested in a flexible control mechanism to manage a pool of asynchronous tasks, I wrote the [`asyncio-taskpool`](https://github.com/daniil-berg/asyncio-taskpool) package to make this easier for my own applications. [`TaskPool.map`](https://asyncio-taskpool.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/asyncio_taskpool.pool.html#asyncio_taskpool.pool.TaskPool.map) allows you to set a specific maximum number of tasks to work concurrently on an arbitrary iterable of arguments. This could help with the rate limiting issue.

Answer (score 2):

As Daniil answered in great detail - I'll just add a simple illustration about how IO works are like, and an alternative design choice.

### About how IO works

As Daniil said, asyncio does not provide parallelism, but provides concurrency.

But - We can achieve IO parallelism in python because python actually doesn't do any of IO works itself (Nor pretty much every user programs). OS does. All Python does meanwhile is *doing nothing*.

And even for CPU, it's not their job to consistently polling every device if IO is done or not - each individual devices send signals(Interrupts) to CPU, then CPU finally starts checking which device's IO work is done.

So, in process/thread's perspective - IO is more like this:

> "Hey OS, please do this IO works for me. Wake me up when it's done."
> Thread 1 goes to sleep
>
> Some time later, OS punches Thread 1
> "Your IO Operation is done, take this and get back to work."

OS does IO works for you, and punches you out of the sleep for you, too - which is called [Interrupt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt).

This is why you see in many applications & frameworks(including asyncio) uses *Threading* to improve throughput in python despite the existence of [Global Interpreter Lock(GIL)](https://docs.python.org/3.10/glossary.html#term-global-interpreter-lock) limiting python code to be ran in only 1 thread at any given time.

That is, despite being limited in parallel execution - python low-level IO codes written in C releases GIL when waiting for OS do it's IO works so other threads' python code can do more useful job than itself.

So, TL;DR script itself is not parallel, but IO can be parallel - all networks jobs are sent (Despite not simultaneously) - and is waiting for server's response simultaneously(Which is doing nothing until OS Interrupt).

---

### Some example

And for producer-consumer pattern-ish example - well, more like pool because there is no pair. Servers will usually ban/cut the connection when there's a lot of simultaneous connections.

But with this approach - we can guarantee that there will only be at best 3 simultaneous connections and won't make server angry.

server.py - receive GET, randomly waits and response:

```py
import asyncio
from random import randint

from quart import request, jsonify, Quart


app = Quart("Very named Much app")


@app.get("/json")
async def send_json():
    """
    Sleeps 0~4 seconds before returning response.

    Returns:
        json response
    """
    key = request.args["user"]
    print("Received " + key)

    await asyncio.sleep(randint(0, 4))
    return jsonify({"user": key})


asyncio.run(app.run_task())
```

client.py:

```py
import asyncio

import httpx


async def request_task(id_, in_queue: asyncio.Queue, out_queue: asyncio.Queue):
    """Get json response data from url in queue. It's Consumer and also Producer.

    Args:
        id_: task ID
        in_queue: Queue for receiving url
        out_queue: Queue for returning data
    """
    print(f"[Req. Task {id_}] Started!")

    # create context for each task
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        while True:
            user = await in_queue.get()
            print(f"[Req. Task {id_}] Processing user '{user}'")

            data = await client.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/json?user=" + str(user))

            # do what you want here
            print(f"[Req. Task {id_}] Received {data}")
            await out_queue.put(data)

            # inform queue that we are done with data we took
            in_queue.task_done()


async def main():
    """
    Starter code
    """

    # create queues
    in_queue = asyncio.Queue()
    out_queue = asyncio.Queue()

    # create consumer tasks
    pool = [asyncio.create_task(request_task(n, in_queue, out_queue)) for n in range(3)]

    # populate queue with numbers as user's name
    for n in range(30):
        in_queue.put_nowait(n)

    # wait for enqueued works are complete
    await in_queue.join()

    # cancel tasks
    for task in pool:
        task.cancel()

    # check data
    print(f"[Main task] Processed {out_queue.qsize()} data!")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

output:

```
[Req. Task 0] Started!
[Req. Task 0] Processing user '0'
[Req. Task 1] Started!
[Req. Task 1] Processing user '1'
[Req. Task 2] Started!
[Req. Task 2] Processing user '2'
[Req. Task 2] Received <Response [200 ]>
[Req. Task 2] Processing user '3'
[Req. Task 1] Received <Response [200 ]>
[Req. Task 1] Processing user '4'
[Req. Task 2] Received <Response [200 ]>
[Req. Task 2] Processing user '5'
[Req. Task 0] Received <Response [200 ]>
[Req. Task 0] Processing user '6'
...

[Req. Task 2] Received <Response [200 ]>
[Req. Task 2] Processing user '22'
[Req. Task 1] Received <Response [200 ]>
[Req. Task 1] Processing user '23'
[Req. Task 0] Received <Response [200 ]>
[Req. Task 0] Processing user '24'
[Req. Task 1] Received <Response [200 ]>
[Req. Task 1] Processing user '25'
[Req. Task 1] Received <Response [200 ]>
[Req. Task 1] Processing user '26'
[Req. Task 2] Received <Response [200 ]>
[Req. Task 2] Processing user '27'
[Req. Task 0] Received <Response [200 ]>
[Req. Task 0] Processing user '28'
[Req. Task 1] Received <Response [200 ]>
[Req. Task 1] Processing user '29'
[Req. Task 1] Received <Response [200 ]>
[Req. Task 2] Received <Response [200 ]>
[Req. Task 0] Received <Response [200 ]>
[Main task] Processed 30 data!
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import trio
import httpx
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'curl/7.72.0'
}

usernames = [
    "author",
    "abtinf",
    "TheCoelacanth",
    "tomcam",
    "chauhankiran",
    "ulizzle",
    "ulizzle",
    "ulizzle",
    "cratermoon",
    "Aeolun",
    "ulizzle",
    "firexcy",
    "kazinator",
    "blacksoil",
    "lucakiebel",
    "ozim",
    "tomcam",
    "jstummbillig",
    "tomcam",
    "johnchristopher",
    "Tade0",
    "lallysingh",
    "paulddraper",
    "WilTimSon",
    "gumby",
    "kristopolous",
    "zemo",
    "aschearer",
    "why-el",
    "Osiris",
    "mdaniel",
    "ianbutler",
    "vinaypai",
    "samtho",
    "chazeon",
    "taeric",
    "yellowapple",
    "Kye",
]


async def worker(limiter, client, user, sender):
    async with limiter, sender:
        while True:
            try:
                r = await client.get(user)
                if r.is_success:
                    break
            except httpx.TimeoutException:
                continue
        await sender.send(r.json())


async def rec(receiver):
    async with receiver:
        allin = []
        async for val in receiver:
            allin.append(val)

        df = pd.DataFrame(allin)
        print(df)


async def main():
    async with httpx.AsyncClient(base_url='https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/users/', headers=headers, timeout=5) as client, trio.open_nursery() as nurse:
        sender, receiver = trio.open_memory_channel(0)
        nurse.start_soon(rec, receiver)
        limiter = trio.CapacityLimiter(10)
        async with sender:
            for user in set(usernames):
                nurse.start_soon(worker, limiter, client, user, sender.clone())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    trio.run(main)
```

Output:

```
         id         username  ... created_at_i         objectID
0    588521         vinaypai  ...   1338822527         vinaypai
1    467662             ozim  ...   1339568697             ozim
2   1062265          chazeon  ...   1606003360          chazeon
3    249733       cratermoon  ...   1379703109       cratermoon
4   1223472          ulizzle  ...   1669998747          ulizzle
5    171849           abtinf  ...   1283894343           abtinf
6    967620        WilTimSon  ...   1565352277        WilTimSon
7   1139106        ianbutler  ...   1549915696        ianbutler
8    742824              Kye  ...   1458260444              Kye
9    199045        aschearer  ...   1337505351        aschearer
10   774096            Tade0  ...   1474198399            Tade0
11   643396        kazinator  ...   1404339283        kazinator
12   880138          firexcy  ...   1523173101          firexcy
13   667410        blacksoil  ...   1412803121        blacksoil
14   608992      yellowapple  ...   1371073015      yellowapple
15   614402             zemo  ...   1268966214             zemo
16   598911           why-el  ...   1326431461           why-el
17   320512            gumby  ...   1276983205            gumby
18   423272          mdaniel  ...   1274588298          mdaniel
19   969129     jstummbillig  ...   1423910369     jstummbillig
20   571671           tomcam  ...   1274062446           tomcam
21   366415  johnchristopher  ...   1311344710  johnchristopher
22   554511           taeric  ...   1284470986           taeric
23   660645           Aeolun  ...   1407842065           Aeolun
24   391694     kristopolous  ...   1306530080     kristopolous
25   803833     chauhankiran  ...   1487269307     chauhankiran
26   516093           samtho  ...   1349474519           samtho
27  1165781       lucakiebel  ...   1644839977       lucakiebel
28   161117    TheCoelacanth  ...   1360938133    TheCoelacanth
29   148275           Osiris  ...   1259518661           Osiris
30   471246      paulddraper  ...   1384317563      paulddraper
31   395353       lallysingh  ...   1217245873       lallysingh
32   202810           author  ...   1361595429           author

[33 rows x 13 columns]
```